# Script for extract Medline abstracts with PMID in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to split below text files with serial number. with `C#` or `vb.net`

```
3 selected items



PubMed Results

Items 1-3 of 3 (Display the 3 citations in PubMed)

1.

Interventions for Anesthetic Success in Symptomatic Irreversible Pulpitis: A Network Meta-Analysis of Randomized Controlled Trials
J Dent Anesth Pain Med. 2019 Dec;19(6):323-341. doi: 10.17245/jdapm.2019.19.6.323. Epub 2019 Dec 27.

Authors

Affiliations

1 Dental Training Department, Ministry of Health, Bahrain.
2 Department of Pharmacology & Therapeutics, College of Medicine and Medical Sciences, Arabian Gulf University, Manama, Bahrain.
PMID: 31942448
PMCID: PMC6946831
DOI: 10.17245/jdapm.2019.19.6.323
Free PMC article

Abstract
Background: Local anesthetics alone or in combination with adjuncts, such as oral medications, have routinely been used for pain control during endodontic treatment. The best clinical choice amongst the vast numbers of agents and techniques available for pain control for irreversible pulpitis is unclear. This network meta-analysis combined the available evidence on agents and techniques for pulpal anesthesia in the maxilla and mandible, in order to identify the best amongst these approaches statistically, as a basis for future clinical trials.

Keywords: Pain; Pulpitis; Root Canal Therapy.

Copyright © 2019 Journal of Dental Anesthesia and Pain Medicine.

Conflict of interest statement
CONFLICT OF INTEREST: None declared.

87 references
5 figures
Full-text links
full-text provider logoThe Korean Dental Society of Anesthesiology Free PMC article

2.

Attitude and Awareness of Dentists Practicing in Southern India Toward Non-steroidal Anti-inflammatory Drugs
J Pharm Bioallied Sci. 2019 May;11(Suppl 2):S355-S359. doi: 10.4103/JPBS.JPBS_33_19.

Authors

Affiliations

1 Department of Oral Medicine and Radiology, Sree Mookambika Institute of Dental Sciences, Kanyakumari Tamil Nadu, India.
2 Department of Pedodontics, Azeezia College of Dental Sciences and Research, Kollam, India.
3 Department of Pedodontics, Government Dental College, Kottayam, Kerala, India.
PMID: 31198368
PMCID: PMC6555374
DOI: 10.4103/JPBS.JPBS_33_19
Free PMC article

Abstract
Background: Pain management is an everyday challenge in dentistry. Analgesics are the group of drugs prescribed for effective pain management, of which nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory drugs (NSAIDs) are the most commonly prescribed drugs. Selection of NSAIDs must be judiciously made considering their pharmacological properties and adverse effects.

Keywords: Analgesics; cyclooxygenase; nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory drugs; pain.

Conflict of interest statement
There are no conflicts of interest.

23 references
2 figures
Full-text links
full-text provider logoMedknow Publications and Media Pvt Ltd Free PMC article

3.

Study of Efficiency and Spectral Resolution for Mathematical Filtration Technique Using Novel Unlimited Derivative Ratio and Classical Univariate Spectrophotometric Methods for the Multicomponent Determination-Stability Analysis
Heliyon. 2019 May 9;5(5):e01669. doi: 10.1016/j.heliyon.2019.e01669. eCollection 2019 May.

Authors

Affiliations

1 Analytical Chemistry Department, Faculty of Pharmacy, Cairo University, Kasr El- Aini Street, 11562 Cairo, Egypt.
2 Pharmaceutical Chemistry Department, Faculty of Pharmaceutical Science and Pharmaceutical Industries, Future University in Egypt, 5th Settlement, 11835 Cairo, Egypt.
PMID: 31193052
PMCID: PMC6514739
DOI: 10.1016/j.heliyon.2019.e01669
Free PMC article

Abstract
Six simple, sensitive and selective spectrophotometric methods based on mathematical filtration technique are presented for concurrent determination of aceclofenac (ACE) and paracetamol (PAR) in presence of their degradation products, namely; diclofenac sodium (DIC) and 4-aminophenol (4-AP), respectively without preliminary physical separation procedures. This technique consists of several consecutive steps applied on built-in spectrophotometer software utilizing zero and/or derivative and/or ratio spectra of the studied components.

Keywords: Analytical chemistry.
```

I want to split paragraph with serial Number. like 1, 2, 3,

Comment: split data with serial numer **1.**  , **2.**,   **3.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code splits the text into four sections (header, and 3 abstracts)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string pattern = @"\r\n\r\n^\d+.\r\n\r\n";

            string[] splitData = Regex.Split(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i nee to split string with..    1.    2.    3.     4.   like this, becuase in my actual file * are not there.

Comment: sir, your earlier code is working for me.. but only 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 but after 10 is not capture with this code . string pattern = @"\n\d\.\s";

Comment: Where is the plus sign?

Comment: Thank you sir, after plus sign it is working perfectly for me..   string pattern = @"\n\d+\.\s";